# Reading Each XML Node in Powershell to create list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, xml, elements-xml

I have an XML file which I got from running webservices of below format. It contains each List name in the site collection under  node. Now using this file I have to create lists in another site collection. And I have to do this using Powershell. I am looking how to iterate through each loop containing list node and how to call its properties required for creating list. BElow is the code I have gone so far:

```
XML Sample: <Lists xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/Lists/20/overview.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{9C3F109C-B99C-4C1C-9515-2389A6FC42B0}" Title="20" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itsurvey.gif" Name="{9C3F109C-B99C-4C1C-9515-2389A6FC42B0}" BaseType="4" FeatureId="00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102" ServerTemplate="102" Created="20150710 11:23:10" Modified="20150710 01:09:42" /><List Doc..
```

Powershell code:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null 
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $XmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument

Get-ChildItem D:\Arpan\ListCollection.xml *.xml -recurse | 
% { 
    $XmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)

    $path =  $XmlDoc.ExportedContentItem.path
    $name =  $XmlDoc.ExportedContentItem.name
    $GUID =  $XmlDoc.ExportedContentItem.ID

    $out = $path + "/" + $name + "`t" + $GUID
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $_.fullname " is  reading to the list item"
```